# Installing Ubuntu on RAID with LVM, failed to boot

Tags: system-installation, raid, lvm

I've installed Ubuntu on RAID-5 with LVM and made a /boot partition but it failed to boot. Can anyone help or point to a resource describing the process?

Update: I decided to re-install the OS.

This question is no longer relevant.

Comment: Does it show GRUB rescue or does it show that there is no bootable drive?

Comment: OK, this means GRUB actually boots but for some reason Ubuntu cannot find RAID or LVM. Can you start it in rescue mode and see what it writes? (If GRUB menu is not showing, you can activate it by holding shift when booting.)

Comment: A black screen with a flashing insert mark. Looks like it is reading, but it's stuck like this.

Comment: It does not seem to work. Just continues showing the black screen.

Comment: This might be embarrassing, what should be the boot device in the BIOS when booting from RAID?

Comment: I am not sure how good Ubuntu installs GRUB on RAID but it should be either any of the disks or the first disk in the array. But you would get message from BIOS that it cannot boot that drive. You could try using [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) but I don't know if it supports RAID.

Comment: This is weird, I tried selecting on of the RAID discs and the machine reboots every time. When I choose another disc it did not reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu can't boot from a software raid in my experience. You need to create a non-raid partition to install GRUB to. Format the partition as fat32 and set boot flag.

Comment: Ubuntu uses GRUB2 which supports booting from RAID-5

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: Despite that GRUB2 supports booting from RAID, I haven't seen a documentation or guide on how to accomplish it. Your solution is the best so far.